# Using xlswrite to export a large matrix from MATLAB to Excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I need to export a matrix which is much larger than the 1024 character limit.  Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: Is does the matrix have more than 1024 elements, or does it contain strings that have more than 1024 characters?

Comment: Do you have a matrix with more than 1024 columns? How bout if transposed? Still exceed 1024 col limit? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have way more control interacting with Excel through [COM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bqdwu3j.html) instead of MATLAB's built-in functions. Below is a small sample of what you can do. Perhaps it can help you write your array.

```
% Open a connection to Excel.
h = actxserver('Excel.Application');

% Make the Excel window visible.
set(h, 'Visible', 1);

% Create a new Excel workbook.
h.Workbooks.Add;

% Get the active Excel worksheet.
hSheet = h.ActiveSheet;

% Write to the cell at (A,1) on the active worksheet.
set(hSheet.Cells, 'Item', 1, 1, 123.456);

% Save and close the workbook.
h.ActiveWorkbook.Save;
h.ActiveWorkbook.Close;
```

Comment: Not sure that this is so much simpler or more powerful than writing `xlswrite('myFile.xls',123.456,1,'A1');`, which writes 123.456 to the cell `A1` in the first sheet of the file `myFile.xls`.

Comment: The above is a very small example of what you can do through COM. My intention was to show Jamie another way of doing the same thing in order to inspire a solution to the current problem and expand the toolbox for future problems.