# Big-Data export from Matlab to a .csv file

Tags: matlab, data-export

I need to create a big .csv file with say 200,000+ rows and 7 cols. This fails:

`a = randn(200000,7) ; xlswrite('hugedata.csv', a) ;`

`??? Error using ==> xlswrite at 211
Excel returned: Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC.`

a = randn(4,3) ; xlswrite('hugedata.csv', a) ; % works perfectly fine.

Comments?  Please suggest an alternative code if available.  Thanks.

Comment: Related/potential duplicate: [Using xlswrite to export a large matrix from MATLAB to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008816/using-xlswrite-to-export-a-large-matrix-from-matlab-to-excel)

Comment: Hi gnovice.  Thanks.  I tried using that approach but am I stuck at the step: `set(hSheet.Cells, 'Item', 1, 1, 123.456);`  I tried passing `a` instead of `123.456` but with no success.  How do I change `1,1` to get the desired result?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the 2003 version of excel, then it can't handle 200000 rows. that is what is returning the error.

Comment: Hi Soandos.  I have Excel 2007.  Is that an issue?  Please comment.

Comment: That version can handle the number of rows...
can you try to save it as a csv but not to excel?

Comment: I can save it as a csv or even a .txt file.  It won't be an issue.  My main problem is how to dump such a huge matrix into an output file which can be later read.